# How to merge two criterias / QueryObjects in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a **QueryObject** object **detached** and I have a second **ICriteria** object **criteria**.

```
        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Theme>()
            .CreateAlias("InceptionCycle", "ic", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .CreateAlias("ClosingCycle", "cc", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.Le("ic.CycleMonth", cycleDate))
            .Add(Restrictions.Or(
                Restrictions.IsNull("cc.ID"),
                Restrictions.Ge("cc.CycleMonth", cycleDate)));

        QueryOver<Theme, Theme> detached = new GlobalTheme().GetQuery();

        // and now how to make new query : detached AND criteria
```

Is it possible to merge/join/add AND condition between this two criteria objects? Something like this (of course following line of code doesn't work as Add method do not accept **ICriteria** type):

```
detached.DetachedCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).Add(criteria).List<Theme>();
```

The reason why I want to achieve is:

- **GlobalTheme** query has some conditions that can be mixed with other criterias
- **ICriteria criteria** has other condition that also can me mixed with other criterias (I'll refactor it to QueryObject in the future)

As a result, in order to handle all combination of **n** possible criterias I would have to create at least n*n **QueryObjects**. If it's possible to AND two or more criterias, I have to create only **n** **QueryObject** types.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to "merge" criteria queries, but what you can do for reuse is create a method that adds whatever restrictions you want to the specified query.

A generic example, using an extension method:

```
var results = session.CreateCriteria<AnEntity>()
                     .Add(aSpecificRestriction)
                     .AddGenericFilters()
                     .List();

public void AddGenericFilters(this ICriteria criteria)
{
    criteria.Add(whatever);
    return criteria;
}
```